# Add Chart in email body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Hi I am using below code to add chart and send email to multiple recipients. It works fine. In my sent item i can see a perfect email created and sent. But all the recipients are not able to see the charts. All they see is two red X

```
Sub Send_Email_Updated()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim NewMail As Object
Dim NewMail1 As Object
Dim ChartName As String
Dim ChartName1 As String
Dim SendingRng As Range
Dim htmlString As String
Dim OMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set S1 = wb.Worksheets("Incident Tickets")
Set S2 = wb.Worksheets("Assets and Representatives")
Set S3 = wb.Worksheets("Email")

'Set SendingRng = Worksheets("Email").Table("A30:C43")
Set SendingRng = Worksheets("Email").Range("A30:C43")
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

' Group 1
If S3.Cells(7, 2) <> 0 Or S3.Cells(8, 2) <> 0 Or S3.Cells(9, 2) <> 0 Then

OMail.Display

'fill in the file path/name of the gif file app graph
    ChartName = Environ$("Temp") & "\Chart 1.gif"

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Email").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Export _
    Filename:=ChartName, FilterName:="GIF"

'fill in the file path/name of the gif file trend graph
    ChartName1 = Environ$("Temp") & "\Chart 31.gif"

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Email").ChartObjects("Chart 31").Chart.Export _
    Filename:=ChartName1, FilterName:="GIF"

    Set NewMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    With NewMail
        .Subject = "Action Required on Incidents and Problem Candidates for GC060.1 - Group 1"
        .To = "animesh.das@xyz.com"

        .HTMLBody = 
        "<img src=" & "'" & ChartName1 & "'>" & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "_
        "<img src=" & "'" & ChartName & "'>" & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & _

        .Send
    End With

    ChartName = vbNullString
    ChartName1 = vbNullString

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `<img src=" & "'" & ChartName1 & "'>"` this points to an image stored in your local drive, so other recipients are not going to be able to access that file

Comment: Can you please suggest if there is any alternate solution for this?

Comment: Is there anyway i can store it in OneDrive and give access to all the recipients and then send email? will it help

Comment: Take a look here for info about embedding images in emails.  https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2013/02/embedded-images-in-html-email/

Comment: Sorry to come back on this again. The Base64 code is too large to add in the code. I will have multiple charts added in email. Can someone please suggest a different solution. also the chart is dynamic hence it will create different image everytime the data is updated but with the same name. Will that not change the base64 code?